# GNU Guile segfaults when loading guile-readline

Tags: scheme, readline, guile

I'm embedding guile in a small program I'm writing, I'm opting to use `guile-readline` as an extension. This extension works perfectly fine the default REPL, `(use-modules (ice-9 readline)) (activate-readline)`.

However, when I try to invoke the same in a REPL instantiated by calling `scm_shell();`, the program segfaults at `scm_init_readline`.

I've found that `(ice-9 readline)` probably, under the hood, invokes `(load-extension "guile-readline" "scm_init_readline")`. Doing this works from the default guile REPL, `guile`, as doing `(provided? 'readline)` will yield `#t` after this invocation.

Still, from a custom REPL invoked via `scm_shell(0, NULL);`, this expression segfaults at `scm_init_readline` (from `/usr/lib/guile/2.2/extensions/guile-readline.so`). The particular instruction in question:

```
repz cmpsb %es:(%rdi),%ds:(%rsi)
```

Having dumped the registers at this point, it's clear that `rsi` is `0` (so what looks to be a memory addressing operand segfaults).

I'm not sure if `scm_shell()` avoids crucial bootstrapping operations that the `guile` REPL itself does.

Any assistance with this issue would be appreciated, I've googled around and found people with similar issues but no resolution.